# DRF How to optimize this query, instead of looping if's?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a query in mind, currently it works as expected in shell with the Django ORM:

```
>>> Place.objects.all()[0].images.filter(order=0)[0].filename
'y5IUMPyv.jpg'
```

But I don't know how to implement it with DRF's SerializerMethodField. This is what I'm using in the meantime until I can figure it out:

```
class CardSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_image(obj):
        for d in obj.images.all():
            if d.order == 0:
                return d.filename
```

This is the "ideal" method that doesn't work, and I don't know why:

```
    @staticmethod
    def get_image(obj):
        return obj.images.filter(order=0)[0].filename
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 201, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 45, in list
    return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/serpy/serializer.py", line 134, in data
    self._data = self.to_value(self.instance)
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/serpy/serializer.py", line 123, in to_value
    return [serialize(o, fields) for o in instance]
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/serpy/serializer.py", line 123, in <listcomp>
    return [serialize(o, fields) for o in instance]
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/serpy/serializer.py", line 107, in _serialize
    result = getter(self, instance)
  File "/home/admin/src/places/serializers.py", line 72, in get_image
    return obj.images.filter(order=0)[0].filename
  File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 297, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: All 'Place' objects has a image with 'order=0'?

Comment: @AndersonLima Thanks, this was the key to solving the problem. It briefly crossed my mind that some of the objects don't have any images, but I wasn't able to make this connection... Lesson learned!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the iron maiden @anderson-lima has pointed out, this is a problem with your data rather than your code. You do not have an image with order = 0 and your first method handles that situation correct if not optimally.

```
@staticmethod
    def get_image(obj):
        for d in obj.images.all():
            if d.order == 0:
                return d.filename

        # returns None here if an object with order = 0
        # does not exist in the database.
```

However in your second approach you are taking a slice but fetching an object that does not exist. Hence the execption, and which in turn tells us that what you need is a just a try except block.

```
@staticmethod
def get_image(obj):
    try:
        return obj.images.filter(order=0)[0].filename
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't make that connection myself, makes perfect sense now. Also, I deleted that other question now, I thought that asking about Serpy was too specific so I rewrote the question using just DRF and forgot to delete the old one, sorry about that. Oddly, Serpy requires the self param in the staticmethod, doesn't work without it... Not the case with DRF serializers.

Comment: Glad it's sorted out.